# How to increase the cell character length in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, html, css, phpexcel

Using PHPExcel created HTML data in and inserted in file,

```
$FinalCSVName = "TEMP_EXCEL";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray( $this->GetFinalDataFieldsXLS( $conn ) , NULL, 'A1');

  foreach( $result as $row ) {
      unset( $row["process_log_id"] );
      unset( $row["SellerID"] );
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($row, NULL, 'A'.$i);
       $i++;
   }

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension("CM")->setAutoSize(true);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter( $objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007' );
$objWriter->save( Constant::MAIN_FOLDER_PATH.Constant::FINAL_EXCEL_PATH.$FinalCSVName.'.xlsx' );
```

Using this code generating .xlsx file, In Column index **CM** inserting html content, Forexample :-

```
<div id="accordion"> <div class="card"> <div class="card-header" id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"><h5 class="mb-0"><button class="btn" ><strong>Summary</strong></button></h5></div><div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion"><div class="card-body"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2"><b>Part Name :...
```

If HTML contents are more than **32768** ( i.e default character length of cell ) it will not write complete **HTML**. 
In My Case the HTML characters length is above **65000**, So it will write **32768** character. This leads to improper UI because HTML is not in proper format. So how would I increase the characters length of cell ?

Comment: Doubtful that you will be able to change a "hard" limit in Excel itself. This almost sounds like a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). What is it that you are trying to solve/do by putting large quantities of HTML in a spreadsheet cell?

Comment: Yes, I am importing products and there is Description column which contains HTML structure. But for few records the HTML charterers length is above 50000. But default limit of excel cell is **32786**. So HTML is not complete and product page is not in proper format.

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel has limits, maybe you can split the html in more cell to avoid this limit.

For example try to split string in array at given dimension:

```
$myHtmlArray = str_split ( $myHtmlVar, 32767 )
```

Then loop trough array a print the corrispondent number of cells

Comment: I cannot split the content into other cell, because I am **importing** this **TMP_EXCEL.xlsx** file to display HTML in UI and Only one feild is there to display HTML content on UI.

Comment: Understand, but this is an excel limit: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

You can maybe compress your html? using small classname, avoiding subclass and targeting based on parent class etc.. ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that solution but after removing space, reducing class name, still there is characters length issue.

Comment: I don't know how your application work and the max lenght of your html, but it's possibile to think to a substitution in saving and substitution back in getting? for example: `class -> [c] | data-toggle -> dtog | data-target -> dtar -> aria-expanded -> aexp ` and so on..

Comment: Its not working for me, because HTML characters length is 70000